# Scala - extending MainFrame(), GridBagPanel() and what about 'reactions'

Tags: swing, scala

In order to keep the app more organised, I have defined in new class for example the `Frame` then the `Panel` or `GridBagPanel` like:

```
class TestGridBagPanel extends GridBagPanel { }
class TestFrame extends MainFrame { 
   contents = new TestGridBagPanel
   reactions = new React // ??
}
class React extends WHAT??  { }

... // and so on and then called in top() method like this:

object TestApp extends SimpleSwingApplication {
  def top = new TestFrame { }
 }
```

My problem is that I am failing to know which Component to `extend` in the Reaction class and I have to listen from `Buttons`, `TextFields` and `CheckBoxes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your React class should be

```
class React extends PartialFunction[Event,Unit]{
    override def isDefinedAt(x: Event): Boolean = ...

    override def apply(e: Event): Unit = e match {
        case e: MouseDragged => {}
        case e: MousePressed => {}
    }
}
```